# ListView like in Holo PreferenceScreen / Spotify

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to build a listview that looks like the one in spotify:

[image: spotify]

Or the one in the Holo Settings:

[holo settings http://en.samaanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/rEGAZ.jpg](http://en.samaanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/rEGAZ.jpg)

More precisely, I want a listview with categories (headers) and items (views) below them. Any help? Should I just try to look into the Settings app layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do it is through a [Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) Activity